Surival Prediction - Train/Test data vs Production data
I have a need to create a churn prediction model and it seems like a survival model fits the bill since my data is right-censored (there are many customers who have yet to churn, or in other words, are event-free up until the last observation). For context, I have been using the scikit-survival library.
I have no experience with survival models except for the last week or so of research, and to be honest I'm not all that experienced in Machine Learning in general. I'm hoping to get some help on a point of confusion for me.
I'm having a hard time understanding which data to use for training/testing vs the data I'll use when my model is in production (to predict survival).
If I were predicting, for example, whether a customer would churn within their first year (subscription-based product), then to me that's simply a logistic regression and they either cancel within their first year or they don't. In that case my training/testing data will be all customers who survived > 1 year, or those who have cancelled. After training/testing, I would then be predicting churn for current customers with age < 1 year.
With a survival model (as I understand it), I'll train the model using right-censored customer data, but aren't these right-censored customers the ones that I'm interested in generating a prediction for? Does that not expose me to overfitting?
Again, I recognize I'm very new to this area, so please let me know if I am just missing something obvious.

Good for diving into this topic, since, anecdotally, most practitioners in the ML/DS space frame these problems as classification which is very problematic. A couple of suggestions: first, keep the number of events at the forefront of your work since this drives a lot of decisions on the approach. Typically, in survival the number of events is low. Second, (corollary to 1st): you may not be able to afford data splitting as you may need all the data to estimate the model (in which case the bootstrap is your friend). Finally, keep in mind that pure ML approaches to survival are data hungry.

It isn't quite correct to say "these right-censored customers [are] the ones that I'm interested in generating a prediction for." You want to generate predictions for all individuals like those of your study population. Right censoring of an individual's event time just limits how much information that individual contributes to the model of the population.
The right censoring typical of survival analysis means that you only have a lower limit for the time to the event of interest. That might be because you lost contact with an individual, or an individual didn't have the event before the end of the study.
A survival model provides information about the time to an event, not just whether the event happened. In a Cox model, the covariate values of an individual experiencing an event are compared against those of all individuals at risk for an event at that time (the risk set). Thus an individual with a right-censored event time provides information for the model up until the last observation time.
If all you care about is, say, the probability of churn before 1 year then you could consider a binomial model. You would have to be careful in setting up the data, however, as those who churned after 1 year would need to be included as not churned at 1 year and you would have to omit those who have been enrolled for less than 1 year. It might be preferable to use a full survival model and generate 1-year survival predictions from it.
This review by Leung et al., Annu Rev Public Health 18: 83-104 (1997), goes into more detail about the types of censoring and their implications for analysis

+1 for suggesting "It might be preferable to use a full survival model and generate 1-year survival predictions from it". In nearly all applications I have seen, I find framing the problem as a survival one is not just more elegant, but usually more informative. Not to mention, power is usually higher.

@EdM, thanks for the explanation. I think I can make my question a little more clear. When fitting my model, do I train/test the model using all individuals (current and churned customers), or a subset of them? Intuition tells me I use a subset of all individuals, and then exclude those individuals from future predictions since they were the samples used for training the model -- does that make sense? Again, sorry if this question sounds really naive, I'm a complete novice in survival modeling.

@QuantumGizmoExplore For a train/test split, proceed as you would in other modeling: choose a training subset from all individuals, then test on the remaining ones. If you have time-varying covariates, however, then survival predictions are tricky and aren't even allowed by some software. You should, however, have at least a few tens of thousands of events before you do a train/test split. Otherwise, bootstrap validation is more reliable. See this web post; it's events (churns) rather than total number of cases that matter in survival.
